# Javascript FOR loop, "var i = 0", loop runs through as expected. However variable is reset to 0, and the loop never ends

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html5-canvas, infinite-loop

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="hypertext">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="Canvas_Container">
        <canvas id="Canvas_1"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var canvas_width = screen.availWidth;
var canvas_height = screen.availHeight;
var canvas_div = window.document.getElementById("Canvas_Container");
canvas_div.innerHTML = "<canvas id='Canvas_1' width='"+canvas_width+"' height='"+canvas_height+"'></canvas>";
var hypertext = document.getElementById("hypertext");
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas_1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var init = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var circle_x = Math.random() * canvas_width
        var circle_y = Math.random() * canvas_height
        var circle = {
        "x": circle_x,
        "y": circle_y,
        "radius": 5,
        "fill": "#000000"
        }
    }
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = circle.fill;
        context.fill();
        requestAnimationFrame(init);
    }
console.log(i)
}
```

As you can see I'm messing around with HTML5 canvas. I logged the variable earlier and I saw that the variable is reaching the limit set by the for loop and then for some odd reason it is resetting to 0, circles are being created infinitely because of this, and the browser crashes. I'm really scratching my head and wondering what's wrong with this one. Any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty new to this whole JavaScript thing.

Comment: What do you think `requestAnimationFrame(init);` does?

Comment: You run the `init` function at `60fps`. And, as for the logging, the `i` variable logs as `3`, not as `0`.

Comment: Yeah, I feel silly now. I should've probably looked into that since I had no idea what it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reset the for loop every time you call requestAnimationFrame;

```
var init = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        requestAnimationFrame(paint);
    }    
}

function paint() {      
    var circle_x = Math.random() * canvas_width
    var circle_y = Math.random() * canvas_height
    var circle = {
        "x": circle_x,
        "y": circle_y,
        "radius": 5,
        "fill": "#000000"
    }
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = circle.fill;
        context.fill();        
    }    
}
```